# How can I make my movement continuous?

Tags: javascript, movement

I'm making a game with simple movement code. I don't want the movement to be too complex since it's going to be a small game once it's done.

Right now the character moves 10 units at a time, then stops, then 10 units, then stops, and this looks jerky.

I'd like the character to move continuously, without stopping in between. I tried lowering the `playerSpeed` to make it less jerky, but then the character moved too slowly and players got bored. Instead I want the character to move a little every frame, not a big jump with delays in between.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
playerSpeed = 10;

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
 if(e.key === 'w' && playerY >= 5){
  playerY-= playerSpeed;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, outerWidth, outerHeight);
  drawProtagonistFacingUp();
} 
 if(e.key == 'd' && playerX < outerWidth - 50){
  playerX+= playerSpeed;
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,outerWidth, outerHeight);
  drawProtagonistFacingRight();
}

if(e.key == 's' && playerY < outerHeight - 100){
 playerY+= playerSpeed;
 ctx.clearRect(0,0,outerWidth, outerHeight);
 drawProtagonistFacingDown();
}

if(e.key == 'a' && playerX > 5){
  playerX-= playerSpeed;
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0,outerWidth, outerHeight);
 drawProtagonistFacingLeft();
}
});
```

Comment: So what's wrong with increasing the movement speed?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You reduced movement speed, testers didn't like it, you changed it back. So what problem do you still have? You said you want "more natural" movement. What exactly do you mean with that? What makes the movement feel "unnatural"? There might be plenty of possible reasons for that.

Comment: @Phillip I mean, when you move in the game, u move 10 pixels at at time. Is there anyway to make it so u move 1 pixel at a time but faster?

Comment: _"Is there anyway to make it so u move 1 pixel at a time but faster?"_ Zoom out? Maybe adding an animated gif (use something like screentogif or gifcam) could help show the behaviour you'd like to improve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The movement isn't smooth because you only move your character when the `keydown` event is emitted which occurs at most a few times per second (I'm not sure how often exactly).

What you want to do instead is, have a boolean variable which tells you whether a key has been pressed (set to true on `keydown`, false on `keyup`). In your main game loop, if the variable is set to on, you would then move the player by `playerSpeed` * `timeDelta` (difference in time between now and the previous iteration, which you can calculate using `getTime`).

Comment: Ok, could you put that in code plz?